# Como ler um contéudo de um URL .txt

Tags: php

Estou tentando ler um conteúdo de um URL, mas da forma que estou fazendo, não estou conseguindo ler.

O conteúdo do URL são apenas números inteiros.

O erro que aparece é:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

```
  <?php
  $url1 = fopen("http://www.url.com/exemplo.txt","r");
  $cont2 = 0;
  while (!feof ($url1)) {
     $cont_url = fgets($url1,4096);
     $cont2 += $cont_url;
  }
  fclose($url1); 
  echo "Conteudo desse arquivo é:" .$cont2.;
 ?>
```

Comment: O erro que aparece é: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: Cara, pra começar, acredito eu que você queira o seguinte: $cont2[] = fgets($url1, 4096). Ou seja, não precisa de 2 linhas pra isso, e você terá um array. E no fim não pode rodar com echo, vai ter que usar foreach ou for.

Comment: Caso precise do outro array, vai ter que botar os dois com [] na frente. No caso não precisa por o índice, porque ele vai buscar o próximo índice vazio

Comment: Você consegue ler esse arquivo pelo *browser*? Demora quanto tempo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra ler o conteúdo diretamente de uma URL usando as funções nativas do PHP, primeiro você precisa certificar-se de duas coisas:

1. A opção [allow_url_fopen](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php) esteja habilitada no PHP
2. Seu servidor consegue sair e pegar essa URL (p.ex.: não há firewall que impeça)

No seu caso, o erro pode estar acontecendo porque o servidor não consegue pegar esse arquivo, fica tentando até dar *timeout*, e depois de 30 segundos o PHP desiste.

Pra fazer o PHP desistir depois de mais de 30 segundos, basta alterar a opção [max_execution_time](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time). Mas se o firewall estiver bloqueando, aumentar esse tempo não vai adiantar nada.

Sendo assim, você pode testar a leitura de um arquivo remoto através de um código simples como esse:

```
<?php
$arquivo = file_get_contents("http://localhost/lab/numeros.txt");
echo "Conteudo do arquivo: \n" . $arquivo;
?>
```

O [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) carrega todo o conteúdo do artigo em uma string, que depois eu mostro com o echo.

Outro jeito de testar é indo no servidor e tentando pegar o arquivo remoto, pra ver se ele chega. Se for Windows, só ir pelo navegador. Se tiver uma shell/linha de comando em Linux/UNIX, pode usar os comandos wget ou curl seguido do endereço do arquivo.

Na lógica do seu exemplo, você lê linha por linha e vai somando os números (um número por linha). Testei aqui e funciona (tirando o ponto depois da concatenação do $cont2 na última linha. Exemplo da shell aqui:

```
$ php numeros.php
Conteudo desse arquivo é: 106709
```